# How to set OOM killer adjustments for daemons permanently?

Tags: linux-kernel, daemon, out-of-memory

Running some Linux servers with single or just a few vital system service daemons, I would like to adjust the OOM killer for those daemonized processes in case something odd happens. For example, today some Ubuntu server running MySQL got a killed MySQL daemon because tons of `apt-checker` processes [were](https://askubuntu.com/q/230553/88802) consuming all memory and the kernel thought it was a good idea to kill MySQL.

I know I can adjust the score using the `/proc/$(pidof mysqld)/oom_score_adj` file to give the kernel some clue I don't prefer MySQL to be killed, yet that doesn't survive a restart of the service. Should I edit init/upstart scripts from the package to include these adjustments? I don't think that's a very elegant solution as I would make adjustments to files belonging to a package. Would it be possible to hook into upstart/init scripts in general and conditionally adjust it? Or would you suggest running an indefinite script like `while true{ adjust_oom(); sleep 60;}`?

Comment: Interesting that there is the possibility to adjust that. I guess that there is nothing better than your infinite loop to accomplish the job. The OOM-killer is buried deep inside the kernel and has a very obscure algorithm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Several modern dæmon supervision systems have a means for doing this.  (Indeed, since there is a chain loading tool for the job, arguably they *all* have a means for doing this.)

- **Upstart:** Use `oom score` in the job file.

  ```
  oom score -500
  ```
- **systemd:** Use the `OOMScoreAdjust=` setting in the service unit.  You can use service unit patch files to affect pre-packaged service units.

  ```
  [Service]
  OOMScoreAdjust=-500
  ```
- **[daemontools family](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html):** Use the `oom-kill-protect` tool from the nosh toolset in the `run` program for the service.

  If you are converting a system service unit, the `convert-systemd-units` tool will in fact convert the `OOMScoreAdjust=` setting into such an invocation of `oom-kill-protect`.

  ```
  #!/bin/nosh
  …
  oom-kill-protect -- -500
  …
  program arguments
  ```

  As a bonus, you can make it parameterizable:

  ```
  oom-kill-protect -- fromenv
  ```

  and set the value of the parameter in the service's environment (presumed to be read from an envdir associated with the service, here manipulated with the nosh toolset's `rcctl` shim):

  ```
  rcctl set servicename oomprotect -500
  ```

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`oom-kill-protect`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/oom-kill-protect.html). nosh toolset. 
  Softwares.
- James Hunt and Clint Byrum (2014).  "[`oom score`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#oom-score)".  *Upstart Cookbook*.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  "[`OOMScoreAdjust`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=)".  `systemd.exec`. systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. [`rcctl`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/rcctl.html). nosh toolset. 
  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409454/5132

Answer (score 9):

This is possible in Ubuntu using Upstart and the `oom score` configuration option.

> [`oom score`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#oom-score)
>
> Linux has an "Out of Memory" killer facility. [...]
>
> Normally the OOM killer regards all processes equally, this stanza
>   advises the kernel to treat this job differently.
>
> The "adjustment" value provided to this stanza may be an integer value
>   from -999 (very unlikely to be killed by the OOM killer) up to 1000
>   (very likely to be killed by the OOM killer). [...]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # this application is a "resource hog"
> oom score 1000
>
> expect daemon
> respawn
> exec /usr/bin/leaky-app
> ```

Comment: For readers using Ubuntu 16.04+, this has become obsolete now that Upstart has been replaced by systemd.

Answer (score 4):

You could hack it into MySQL itself (e.g. OpenSSH's `sshd` does this), yet that's a bit too hardcore and very dirty (problems with updates etc.)

You can do this in a wrapper or in the init script - the score should be inherited (and in a wrapper you would probably want to do `exec mysqld "$@"` anyway).

Use `cgroups` - it will give you a bit more flexibility and it can be made permanent in the sense, that the appropriate settings can be applied automatically on service restart. See e.g. [controlling priority of applications using cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups) for more info. To achieve the automatism you are looking for, you'll probably want to take a look at [libcgroup](http://libcg.sourceforge.net), which contains a daemon that can handle changing cgroups of a running process on the fly according to a set of rules, or just use the `cgexec` wrapper (from the same package).