# How to limit CPU performance for KVM VM?

Tags: linux, debian, kvm

imagine 1 Virtual machine with 2 shared cores on quad core CPU 2Ghz speed.

Is it possible to limit this Virtual Machine for 500Mhz of CPU power on both cores? Or to reserve 1Ghz on 1 core for this one VM?

Is it possible to limit for example to 1500Mhz for 2 VMs ? 
I mean to share 1500Mhz of power of 1 core for 2 VMs.

For example VMware ESXI and Citrix Xenserver can do it easily by creating resource pool where you preshare for example 2x 1Ghz cores and 4GB ram and then you give there for example just only 2 or 10 VMs as you wish. Is it possible in KVM? How? If is, can it do some kind of web based interface for KVM?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve reasonably fine-grained resource allocation with [cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups) - the advantage is, that it allows you to have **guaranteed** reserved resources, which are available for all processes when not used by the applications in the cgroup to which they are allocated.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me more about that? Disadvantages + advantages? Is there any other option?