# Run Linux process at very very low priority?

Tags: process, cpu, htop, priority, nice

I have a regular process that's not so important but will consume very much CPU power. I have another process which is really important, but it spends most of the time idle, but when it gets a job it really needs high computing power.

I tried running with `nice -20 ./low_priority_process` and `nice --20 ./high_priority_process` but still the lower priority process consumes significant amount of CPU when the high priority process is in need.

How can I run a process that will really yield or even auto-suspend when another process is using CPU power?

Comment: How are you determining that the high priority process is actually in need?

Comment: it will spawn a lot of threads, or the process eat the cpu more than 50% of cpu capacity

Comment: Use `RR` scheduling for the high priority process.

Comment: @Ramesh What possible difference will that make?

Comment: I'm way too late to the party, but I can see from your use case that you're having issues not only with the CPU usage, but also with the I/O and RAM memory. Playing HQ videos consumes a lot of CPU, hdd I/O and RAM memory at the same time. Your issue is probably NOT (only) CPU.

Comment: Contrary to a common misconception, running a "nice" process does not mean, it will _never_ run while regular processes have anything to do. It only means, it will run _less often_. To get, what you want on BSD systems there are `idprio` and `rtprio` to run things at "idle" and "real time" priorities respectively. On Linux you may have to go the `cgroup`-route, as @peterph suggested...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), it should provide exactly what you need - CPU reservations (and more). I'd suggest reading [controlling priority of applications using cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups).

That said, put the important yet often idle processes into group with allocated 95% of CPU and your other applications into another one with allocated 5% - you'll get (almost) all of the power for your jobs when needed, while the constantly power hungry process will only get 5% at most at those times. When the computational surges disappear all CPU performance will be thrown at the remaining processes. As a benefit, if you create a special cgroup (with minimal performance requirements) for processes like `sshd`, you'll be able to log in no matter what is trying to get all CPU it can - some CPU time will be reserved for `sshd`.

Comment: is there a command like `cpulimit` or `nice` to modify the cgroup of process? because i if cgroup is an API call, i am in position can't recompile any of those app to use cgroup

Comment: No, you just mount the cgroup hierarchy somewhere, create per-group directories and write PIDs of processes into some files. All this has to be done as root (or, more precisely with appropriate privileges). Some init systems (namely `systemd`, at least in some cases) "steal" the cgroups interface from users who have to use the init system interface (usually a special command). Read the linked answer and wikipedia article. Really. :)

Comment: Oh, and there is also `libcgroup` package, which comes with utilities for working with cgroups including a daemon (`cgrulesengd`) that can actually sort processes into groups depending on some conditions.

Answer (score 10):

If the process priority (nice value) is low then it will not be interrupting a higher priority process. The reason you're seeing the low priority process still consuming a significant amount of CPU when the higher priority process is running is because the higher priority process is not **that** busy. Probably waiting on IO. Use `chrt -p -i 0 $PID` to run the process at an even lower priority than `nice 19 -p $PID` (assuming we're talking about Linux here).

`chrt -p -i 0 $PID` puts the process into the "true" idle scheduler.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrt

Comment: chrt -p -i 0 $PID

Comment: chrt is still not enough. What I'm trying to do is to watch videos while reencode other videos in the background. Using chrt helped with youtube videos but very high quality mkvs still skip. What I wished is to playback my video normally but use every bit of CPU power remaining for reencoding because I have a huge batch to do.

Comment: @soger Is your video encoding process GPU accelerated? it could potentially be a resource contention issue with your GPU?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs No, it is not.

Comment: Is your hard disk busy? See `ionice`.

Comment: @KenSharp @soger `sudo ionice -c Idle -p PID_HERE` :D

Comment: `ionice -c3 command` There is no reason to use `sudo`.

Comment: No, it's not a hard disk problem either. Youtube uses no hard disk and mplayer would complain if it were running out of buffer.

Answer (score 1):

For future-comers, here is a full example of `nice` with [stress](https://superuser.com/a/443409/642842).

1. The test machine has 2 CPUs

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2 
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  2
...
```

2. Install `stress`: `apt-get install stress`
3. Make the 2 CPUs busy with a low-priority call to stress: `nice -20 stress --cpu 2`
4. Check CPU usage with `top`:

```
                                                 v
                                                 v
                                                 v
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                   
15894 ubuntu    39  19    8240     96      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:06.43 stress                                                                                    
15895 ubuntu    39  19    8240     96      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:06.42 stress
```

This shows that both CPUs are fully occupied.

6. Launch a single-cpu stress process with high priority: `nice --20 stress --cpu 1`
7. Check cpu usage again with `top`

```
                                                 v
                                                 v
                                                 v
                                                 v
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                   
15928 ubuntu    20   0    8240    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:24.02 stress                                                                                    
15894 ubuntu    39  19    8240     96      0 R  51.2  0.0   1:12.46 stress                                                                                    
15895 ubuntu    39  19    8240     96      0 R  48.8  0.0   1:12.35 stress
```

This shows that the single-core stress process gets its full CPU, whereas the lower-priority processes both share the remaining 1 cpu

8. On the other hand, killing all the above `stress` calls and just triggering a single 3-process `stress --cpu 3` would give 66% CPU to each

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to run a process as a low process.

If you're job is nice **tar xvf asets.zip**

Use

### nice tar xvf assets.zip

After that, issue

top to monitor the process unzip with

### ps aux | grep "tar"

Try something specific with **cpulimit**

```
wget -O cpulimit.zip https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit/archive/master.zip
unzip cpulimit.zip
cd cpulimit-master
make
sudo cp src/cpulimit /usr/bin
```

### cpulimit -l 50 python 0 9999999999 > /dev/null &