# How to slow down grep and zgrep on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, grep, performance

I have a bunch of big log files (more than 4 GB)  and i can't download them from sever (download speed is limited) so I need to perform grep and zgrep on a production server. But performing grep or zgrep consumes a log of CPU resources and it affects the performance of a production system.

Is there any way to "slow down" just grep or zgrep command or restrict it in using CPU resources? 
For example, some key that tells grep command to stop working for 0.3 seconds after scanning for 0.7 seconds?

My environment is Linux CentOS 6.9

Comment: Maybe related: [Run linux process at very very low priority?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156915/run-linux-process-at-very-very-low-priority)

Comment: Maybe [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) with the `--rate-limit` option?

Comment: `nice`, `ionice` and `chrt` are essential tools of a Linux admin, but if you want to truly limit the process see http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2015/04/throttling-cpu-usage-with-linux-cgroups.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available in the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) (`yum install epel-release`), there is the `cpulimit` package providing the `cpulimit` command:

> ```
> Usage: cpulimit [OPTIONS...] TARGET
>    OPTIONS
>       -l, --limit=N          percentage of cpu allowed from 0 to 400 (required)
> ```
>
> [...]

It's working by monitoring the target process and regularly sending SIGSTOP/SIGCONT signals to force it to be scheduled out. The CentOS6 version is more limited than current version (which can also monitor children of target).

So if for example you have this busy loop:

```
$ time sh -c 'n=0; while [ $n -lt 50000 ]; do n=$(($n+1)); done'

real    0m0.623s
user    0m0.546s
sys     0m0.076s
```

Choosing to limit CPU usage to 10% gets for example:

```
$ time cpulimit -l 10 sh -c 'n=0; while [ $n -lt 50000 ]; do n=$(($n+1)); done'

real    0m7.695s
user    0m0.795s
sys     0m0.179s
```

What matters here (for this non-multithreaded CPU-bound example) is that user time is now about 1/10 of real time.

The command can also be used on a running process by providing `-p <PID>` instead of a command.

This command is also available on CentOS7 (but not CentOS8).

---

A probably better way would be to use [cgroups](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/cgroups.7#CGROUPS_VERSION_1).

On a more recent system I would rather use cgroups to let the kernel handle all the limitations itself, but I don't have the easy means to test this for CentOS6 (with a container). Here are pointers about it, the first for CentOS6:

[CGroups on CentOS 6](https://beginlinux.com/server/centos/cgroups-on-centos-6)
[Restricting process CPU usage using nice, cpulimit, and cgroups](https://scoutapm.com/blog/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups#149)

If your actual problem is disk I/O trashing rather than CPU, then I think [only cgroups v2 can handle it correctly](https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/) (including disk cache together with memory), but AFAIK it's not available on CentOS6' kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially use the `nice` command. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)):

> nice is a program found on Unix and Unix-like operating systems such
>   as Linux. It directly maps to a kernel call of the same name. nice is
>   used to invoke a utility or shell script with a particular CPU
>   priority, thus giving the process more or less CPU time than other
>   processes. A niceness of -20 is the highest priority and 19 is the
>   lowest priority. The default niceness for processes is inherited from
>   its parent process and is usually 0.
>
> nice becomes useful when several processes are demanding more
>   resources than the CPU can provide. In this state, a higher-priority
>   process will get a larger chunk of the CPU time than a lower-priority
>   process. Only the superuser (root) may set the niceness to a lower
>   value (i.e. a higher priority)

If you want to run a process, such as `grep`, you can use `nice` to set the priority to `19` or something in the teens so it does not hog all of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Mark Plotnick the [**pv**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) utility  helps in a very simple way. Just for grep and zgrep it is indeed very simple:

```
zcat web.log.2020-01-17.log.gz | pv -L 10m -q | grep someText
```

or for grep:

```
cat web.log.2020-01-17.log |  pv -L 10m -q | grep someText
```

The transfer rate 10m (10 megabytes per second) slows down CPU consumption on my server to approximately 8% and keeps it low.

The advantage of pv is simplicity, the disadvantage is that you need empirically determine the appropriate transfer rate for your server.
In CentOS6 **pv** is available after installation with *yum install pv*