# How to ensure ssh via cgroups on centos?

Tags: ssh, cpu, sshd, cgroups

When some cpu-intensive processes are running on the server, chances are that we could not log in to this machine with error 'operation timeout' via `ssh` command.

According to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups) answered by peterph, there should be a way to guarantee sshd service on any circumstances. But I just don't know how to **create a group for sshd, give it some non-negligible CPU time share, and give this "remote access" processes much higher CPU share then the rest**.

Could anyone tell me how can I configure it in `/etc/cgconfig.conf` and `/etc/cgrules.conf`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the man pages? Both `cgconfig.conf(5)` and `cgrules.conf(5)` have nice examples, it shouldn't be difficult modifying those to match your needs. You will probably want to start from something like *(be warned I have not tested it)*:

In `/etc/cgrules.conf`:

```
root:sshd       *               sshdcg/
*               *               default/
```

and `/etc/cgconfig.conf`:

```
mount {
    cpu = /mnt/cgroups/cpu;
    cpuacct = /mnt/cgroups/cpu;
}

group sshdcg {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares = "128";
    }
}
```

Remember you will also need to have `cgrulesengd` running.

Comment: Hey, I'm wondering, will it be the same whether I login as root or a common user? If I control `root:sshd`, does all the ssh login procedures will be 'protected' by the group sshdcg?

Comment: cgroups are inherited by children processes. Thus when `sshd` forks to handle your connection, I would expect it to stay in the same group (especially since the fork is done with the credentials running the listener process. However, the way OpenSSH handles the connections is a bit more complicated - I won't tell you off the top of my head whether there is a place in the login process where it will end up in the default group (with the above setup).